# Intellij can't open the folder where my JDK is located

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am trying to install Intellij IDEA Ultimate on a Linux Mint System.

I entered my project structure settings and then clicked the "+" sign and selected JDK.

I went to browse to my /usr/bin folder but I get the following error:

> The selected directory is not a valid home for JDK

If I type "whereis java" in terminal I get the following output:

> java: /usr/bin/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz

Do you have any suggestions as to why it won't load that folder or how I can properly setup my JDK?

EDIT: Have also tried directly typing in the path but also fails.

Comment: Looks like you may not have a complete Java SDK installed on your Linux Mint machine. What does your system respond if you type in a terminal window `java --version`?

Comment: "openjdk 11.0.1 2018-10-16"

Comment: okay that looks good, so a complete java *is* installed and available. check that that a java directory with that same name/version exist in the `/opt/java/` directory. Or if you type `ls -al /usr/bin/java` look in the directory that linker points to.

Comment: So I just looked and there is no java folder in /opt/

Comment: what does `ls -al /usr/bin/java` point to?

Comment: "/etc/alternatives/java"

Comment: check the version in `"/etc/alternatives/java"`, is `openjdk 11.0.1 2018-10-16` in there? if not what does `ls -al /etc/alternatives/java` point to?

Comment: No java folder there either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189492/discussion-between-davedwards-and-dmellon).

Comment: Unfortunately, still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue thanks to help from @davedwards.

Download the tar.gz distribution from [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html#section=linux). Extract it to a location on your system then CD into the bin folder and launch using ./idea.sh